# Excel formula contains error

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have an error in this excel formula and I can't just figure it out:

```
=LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3&",")-1)&","&RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("&",B3&"&")),RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","@",LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""))))&", "&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("&",B3&"&")-1),RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","@",LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""))))),""))
```

It may seem like a big formula, but all it's intended to do is if no ampersand is in a cell, return an empty cell, if no comma but ampersand exists, then return this, for example:

KNUD J & MARIA L HOSTRUP

into this:

HOSTRUP,MARIA L

Otherwise, there is no ampersand but there is a comma so we just return: LEFT(A1,FIND("&",A1,1)-1).

Seems basic, but formula has been giving me error message and doesn't point to the problem.

Comment: It would probably help if you broke up your very long formulas into seperate (hidden?) cells

Answer (score 4):

Your error is here:

```
=LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3&",")-1)&","&RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("&",B3&"&")),
```

At this point, the comma doesn't apply to anthing, because the right operator has matching parens

As far as what you want? Let's break that up into what you actually asked for:

> if no ampersand in a cell, return empty cell,

```
B4=Find("&", B3&"&")
B5=IF(B4>LEN(B3),"",B6)
```

> if no comma but ampersand exists

```
B6=IF(FIND(",", B3&",")>LEN(B3),B8,B7)
```

then turn this, for example:

> KNUD J & MARIA L HOSTRUP
>   into this:
>   HOSTRUP,MARIA L

I'm presuming you mean to put the last whole word? Let's mark the last whole word:

```
B9=SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","@",LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","")))
B10=RIGHT(B7,LEN(B9)-FIND("@",B9))
```

And the stuff between the ampersand and the last word

```
B11=TRIM(MID(B9,B4 + 1, LEN(B9)-FIND("@",B9)-1))
```

Then calculating it is easy

```
B7=B10&","&B11
```

> Otherwise, there is no ampersand but there is a comma so we just return:
>   LEFT(A1,FIND("&",A1,1)-1).

Well, if you want that, let's just put that in B8

```
B8=LEFT(A1,FIND("&",A1,1)-1)
```

(But I think you actually mean B3 instead of A1)

```
B8=LEFT(B3,FIND("&",B3,1)-1)
```

And there you have it (B5 contains the information you're looking for) It took a few cells, but it's easier to debug this way. If you want to collapse it, you can (but doing so is more code, because we can reduce duplication by referencing a previously calculated cell on more than one occasion).

Summary:

```
B3=<Some Name with & or ,>
B4=FIND("&", B3&"&")
B5=IF(B4>LEN(B3),"",B6)
B6=IF(FIND(",", B3&",")>LEN(B3),B7,B8)
B7=B10&","&B11
B8=LEFT(B3,FIND("&",B3,1)-1)
B9=SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","@",LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","")))
B10=RIGHT(B9,LEN(B9)-FIND("@",B9))
B11=TRIM(MID(B9,B4 + 1, LEN(B9)-FIND("@",B9)-1))
```

When I put in "KNUD J & MARIA L HOSTRUP", I get "HOSTRUP,MARIA" in B5.

Comment: @JohnMerlino I've updated it to get the answer you say you want.

Comment: I have to apply this to 800,000 records all in a single column

Comment: @JohnMerlino Oh, then first move the calculation cells to the right of the data, and copy all of the calculation records down to all 800,000

Comment: For me B5 contains this: KNUD J  And Excel also gave me a circular reference message.

Comment: Is your formula tested? I tried it again and got circular reference warning.

Comment: @JohnMerlino Yes, it is tested in Excel 2007